# OAuth2 Client for Reddit, written using Tornado

Tags: python, reddit, tornado

I have a written some code which helps me to get OAuth Access Code from Reddit. Reddit uses standard OAuth2, so like any other OAuther server, here's are the steps to perform:

1. The client/app sends app key, app secret and redirect URL to browser.
2. User authorizes it and gives permission.
3. Reddit sends request back, with `code` to earlier given redirect URL.
4. The `code` can be used for further access.

The way my script works:

1. I am using praw. I first create a praw object and pass this to server code with required info like app key, app secret and redirect URL:

   ```
   oauthserver = PrawOAuth2Server(reddit_client=reddit_client,
                                  app_key=app_key,
                                  app_secret=app_secret,
                                  state=user_agent)
   ```
2. Start the server. This opens the URL in browser and prompts user for authorization. Most of the magic happens at this stage. This not only starts the server (to handle `redirect_url` request), but also receives the `code`:

   ```
   oauthserver.start()
   ```
3. Then later I can get the access code, refresh token using one of Praw's method:

   ```
   oauthserver.get_access_codes()
   ```

Example usage code:

```
import praw
from PrawOauth2Server import PrawOAuth2Server

user_agent = '...'
app_key = '...'
app_secret = '...'
scopes = ['identity', 'submit']

reddit_client = praw.Reddit(user_agent=user_agent)
oauth_server = PrawOAuth2Server(reddit_client,
                                app_key=app_key,
                                app_secret=app_secret,
                                state=user_agent)
oauth_server.start()
print(oauth_server.get_access_codes())
```

Finally, here is the code I want to be reviewed:

```
import webbrowser

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


REDIRECT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:65010/authorize_callback'
SCOPES = ['identity']
REFRESHABLE = True
CODE = None


class AuthorizationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        global CODE
        CODE = self.get_argument('code')
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().stop()


class PrawOAuth2Server:

    def __init__(self, reddit_client, app_key, app_secret,
                 state, redirect_url=REDIRECT_URL, scopes=SCOPES,
                 refreshable=REFRESHABLE):
        self.reddit_client = reddit_client
        self.app_key = app_key
        self.app_secret = app_secret
        self.state = state
        self.redirect_url = redirect_url
        self.scopes = set(scopes)
        self.refreshable = refreshable
        self.code = None

        self._set_app_info()

    def _set_app_info(self):
        self.reddit_client.set_oauth_app_info(self.app_key, self.app_secret,
                                              self.redirect_url)

    def get_auth_url(self):
        return self.reddit_client.get_authorize_url(self.state,
                                                    self.scopes,
                                                    self.refreshable)

    def start(self):
        global CODE
        url = self.get_auth_url()
        webbrowser.open(url)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
        self.code = CODE

    def get_access_codes(self):
        return self.reddit_client.get_access_information(self.code)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/authorize_callback', AuthorizationHandler),
])
application.listen(65010)
```

1. I want any general suggestion/advice related to above code
2. I really want to change the way I am handling `CODE` (fetching it from request object, using it as global variable etc). I am not able to find way to make this better.

Comment: This goes outside the scope of codereview, but are you trying to write a bot or an actual app? Because if you're writing a reddit bot you don't actually need to start up your own OAuth server.

Comment: I am trying to write a bot. Reddit is going to drop login support and all bots/scripts have to use Oauth only. So, I want to turn my code into a library so that its easier for beginner. Also, can you tell me why it is out of scope for CR and how do I edit to make it come under the required guidelines and scope?

Comment: I am aware, and I recently wrote a bot under the same constraints. The server is 100% unnecessary even for OAuth. Take a look at this: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example